# Bad status for request error in Impala

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, impala

I have copied multiple files data from s3 in one temp external table with location. And now i am copying same data into another partitioned table. While running after 40-50% its showing below error..

My Queries(HUE-Impala):

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS tbl_request_main (
a string,b int,c string)
PARTITIONED BY (year int,month int,day int)
STORED AS PARQUET;

Create table IF NOT EXISTS tbl_request_temp (
a string,b int,c string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://request';

select * from tbl_request_temp; #No error..Getting Result

INSERT INTO tbl_request_main partition (year=2016,month=07,day=07) select * from tbl_request_temp;
```

Error!!

> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> Bad status for request 1631: TGetOperationStatusResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=None, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, infoMessages=None, statusCode=0), operationState=5, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None)

What the issue with impala?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hive uses '\1' for the field delimiter. your main table is created with default `RAW FORMAT` which is not same as your temp table. you can check detailed table info and compare `field delimiter` for both tables (run from hive shell)

`DESCRIBE FORMATTED tbl_request_main` and `DESCRIBE FORMATTED tbl_request_temp`

so both tables should have same `ROW FORMAT`. Re-create `tbl_request_main` and then run `INSERT` statement.

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS tbl_request_main (a string,b int,c string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
PARTITIONED BY (year int,month int,day int)
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

you can upgrade impala to get detailed error message - [HUE-2307](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2307)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have tried again withROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS PARQUET                                       Still getting same error its not showing for select statement but for insertion

Comment: does these insert statements runs ok from `hive` shell?